# exit code 128, what's the reason?

Tags: linux, bash, exit, exit-code

As per definition exit code 128 means 'invalid exit argument'.
But i always get 255 (Exit status out of range) in case argument is invalid like float number.

Is this the proprietary implementation on my linux distribution?

```
# exit 1.234
exit
bash: exit: 1.234: numeric argument required

$ echo $?
255   //this should be 128?

# exit -1
exit

$ echo $?
255   //this is okay
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is nothing within [Bash documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html) that says `128` is the required invalid exit code.

> Bash itself returns the exit status of the last command executed, unless a syntax error occurs, in which case it exits with a non-zero value.

The last command is the bash builtin `exit` (from man page)

> exit [n]
>
> Cause the shell to exit with a status of n.  If n is omitted, the exit status is that of the last command executed.

Checked [specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wait.html) for WEXITSTATUS.

> WEXITSTATUS(stat_val)
>
> If the value of WIFEXITED(stat_val) is non-zero, this macro evaluates to the **low-order 8 bits** of the status argument that the child process passed to _exit() or exit(), or the value the child process returned from main().

So exit is restricted to an 8 bit integer ( 0 - 255 ), so `-1` would be `255`.  Exit only understands an integer argument and not floats, so it's likely kicking out a default `-1`.

```
bash$ echo $BASH_VERSION
4.1.10(4)-release

bash$ exit foo
exit
bash: exit: foo: numeric argument required
$ echo $?    
255

bash$ exit 2
exit
$ echo $?
2

bash$ exit -2
exit
$ echo $?
254
```

Answer (score 1):

This is specific to your shell variant. This http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_08
or http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#exit do not confirm your impression that 128 is some special exit code.

For `exit 3.45` my versions of ksh and zsh return 3, tcsh returns 1 (does not actually exit), and ash returns 2 (but also does not actually exit).

Comment: Other than a few exit codes, exit codes are not standardized.  Also 0 means success, > 0 means some sort of failure.